# using mongodb with node js to make a chat system with history

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, chat, history

trying to make a chat with history, I get few problems with mongodb and node js
to be clear :
I can save a new message in a mongodb collection
**part of the code :**

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');


    collection.insert({message:mess}, function(err, docs) {
        console.log("//////////////\r\n mess insertion :"+mess);
        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log(format("count = %s", count));
        });
    });
```

but I can't read stuff from th mongodb
**I've tried :**

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');

    console.log("Printing docs from Cursor Each")

    // Find all records. find() returns a cursor

    // Print each row, each document has an _id field added on insert
    // to override the basic behaviour implement a primary key factory
    // that provides a 12 byte value

    collection.find().each(function(err, doc) {

    console.log(doc);
    if(doc != null) {
        console.log("Doc from Each ");
        console.dir(doc);
    }
});
```

but without success, it returns " null" as result, which sound strange to me :(

many thanks in advance for your help on this !:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it's working fine.

It's normal for `doc` to be `null` on the last invocation of the `each` callback as an indication that the cursor is exhausted (see the comment in the example code of the [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#each) for `each`).

All I did to your code was add a trailing `});` so that it would run:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');

    console.log("Printing docs from Cursor Each")

    collection.find().each(function(err, doc) {

        console.log(doc);
        if(doc != null) {
            console.log("Doc from Each ");
            console.dir(doc);
        }
    });
});
```

Which outputs:

```
Printing docs from Cursor Each
{ _id: 5480e2667baf089e0b055c7a,
  message: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' }
Doc from Each 
{ _id: 5480e2667baf089e0b055c7a,
  message: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' }
{ _id: 5480e293744a68a90b3f44fb,
  message: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' }
Doc from Each 
{ _id: 5480e293744a68a90b3f44fb,
  message: 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog' }
null
```

I ran your `insert` code twice with that `message` to add the two docs it's showing.

```
var mess = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');

    collection.insert({message:mess}, function(err, docs) {
        console.log("//////////////\r\n mess insertion :"+mess);
        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log("count = %s", count);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment, could you please show me the code you used ? :)

Comment: and what to do with the cursor then...? as it's quiet different from mysql queries I'm not sure to get the way to list data from a collection... :s Thanks again !

Comment: tested:    collection.find().each(function(err, doc) {


collection.find({},function(err,doc){
    //do stuff with doc and err
console.log(doc);
 });
    }
);and  this is showing :

Comment: Printing docs from Cursor Each
{ db:
   { domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _maxListeners: 10,
     databaseName: 'gt-chat',
     serverConfig:
      { domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _callBackStore: [Object],
        _commandsStore: [Object],
        auth: [Object],
        _dbStore: [Object],
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 27017,

Comment: sorry my english is not perfect as it should but so, where are my data ? and how to show them ? thanks m8 ! :)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but as I'm not sure about my insertion routine how did you insert the data? could you show me your piece of code please ? thanks ! :)

Comment: mine code is about : mess="<strong>"+time+"</strong><span style='color:"+color+"'><b>"+pseudo+"</b></span><em> "+message+"</em>";

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');


collection.insert({message:mess}, function(err, docs) {
console.log("//////////////\r\n mess insertion :"+mess);
       collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log(format("count = %s", count));
        });
        });

Comment: as result with your code, i still get "null":     Printing docs from Cursor Each
null

Comment: I used your code for insert as well and your question said that your insert code was working. Have you confirmed your docs are being created in the `gt-chat` collection?

Comment: Well I thought my code was working for insert data, but I'm not sur now... :/ please show me the whole code you have used ( as well the part for insert data ) , I'd like to understand, thanks m8 ! :)

Comment: @guibs See updated answer.  Again, I used your code as is, only adding a closing `});`. Be sure you're not closing `db` before the `insert` calls its callback.

Comment: Hi, it's working now, I don't know really why, but it does ! so thanks for this first step !^^

Comment: Now, it 's showing as result:_____________________ { _id: 5486ba23cdc4ee9827aed844,
  message: '<strong>10:00:19</strong><span style=\'color:FF80BF\'><b>guibs</b></
span><em> hum</em>' } I need to get only the message value, and limit the results to 20. So,,How to get this ? thanks in advance :)

Comment: I know that's in the find() routine, I must add some parameters to filter the results, but I don't know how and where to do that :s thanks again ;)

Comment: @guibs Great. Please close this question out by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Create a new question for your follow-up question.

Answer (score 2):

You are chaining onto the query. That means you are running the .each loop on the mongo cursor.  What you want do is pass the query a callback.

```
collection.find({},function(err,doc){
    //do stuff with doc and err
 })
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting upvotes. `doc` would be the cursor if you did this. `each` is actually the right way to go here.